# JComboBox NullPointerException error

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to update other Jcomboboxes(With ItemStateChanged Event) from jComboBox1 .
I'm finding it hard to know why the below code is throwing Null Pointer Exception . (jComboBox5 is been updated via jComboBox1 ) when i try to select an element from jComboBox1 i get NPE .

```
  private void jComboBox3ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            System.out.println("Count" + jComboBox3.getItemCount());
            if(jComboBox3==null)
            {
                System.out.println("xczxzvzvvxzxzxc999");
            }
            if (jComboBox3.getItemCount() > 1) {
                System.out.println("Selected 3 element"+jComboBox3.getSelectedItem());
     /*Line 1136*/           if (jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("New Payment Term") == true) {
                    jComboBox3.setSelectedIndex(0);
                    ims.MainWindow.jDesktopPane1.add(new ims.Payment.PaymentTerms("Cust"), javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Below is the stackTrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ims.Customer.CustomerFrame.jComboBox3ItemStateChanged(CustomerFrame.java:1136)
    at ims.Customer.CustomerFrame.access$100(CustomerFrame.java:22)
    at ims.Customer.CustomerFrame$2.itemStateChanged(CustomerFrame.java:387)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1225)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1273)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1329)
```

Comment: It looks like you accidentally put your entire question in a code block, as opposed to just the code.

Comment: it looks like JComboBox3.getSelectedItem() is returning a null

Comment: No need to add `==true` to the end of a condition: replace `jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("New Payment Term") == true` by `jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("New Payment Term")`

Answer (score 1):

To find the cause of a `java.lang.NullPointerException` put a breakpoint on the line the exception occurred at, 1136 in this case and investigate the variables on that line.

My guess is that `jComboBox3.getSelectedItem()` is returning `null`.